# How can I number a 2D 10x10 Game Board object?

Tags: java

I am creating a Snakes and Ladder game in Java. I am trying to figure out a way to number the board I created so I can label where the snakes and ladders will be on the board somehow.

The board is supposed to be 10X10.

here is my Board.java class with the following code:

```
public class Board {
    private boolean snake;
    private boolean ladder;
    private int number;
    
    Board(){
        snake = false;
        ladder = false;
        number = 0;
    }
    
    public static void fillBoard(Board[][] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
               // a[i][j] = add some way to increment a number here 
        }
    }
```

Here is my Play.java class where the board object is created.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Play{
    //create object of the board class
    public static int numRows = 10; // number of rows 
    public static int numCols = 10; // number of columns  
    public static Board[][] board = new Board[numCols][numRows];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Board.fillBoard(Board[][]));
    }
}
```

I am just look for a bit of guidance on how I can fill the board with increasing numbers from 1-100. I tried to create fillBoard() method but I am not sure how to finish it or if it is a good way to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter variable here. Assign in the innerloop the counter to your array element and then increment the counter after every assignment.

Currently the type of your 2D array is board, to use the solution below you have to switch the type to int.

```
 public static void fillBoard(Board[][] a) {
        int counter = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
               a[i][j] = counter;
               counter ++;
        }
    }
```

Also your fillBoard method has as return type void which means it doesn't return anything. This means that will not work.

```
    System.out.println(Board.fillBoard(Board[][]));
```

You can import Arrays and then you can use its method `Arrays.deepToString()`which allows you to print nested Arrays.
Here you ll find more

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-deeptostring-in-java-with-example/

Comment: I am getting this error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Board. It is suggesting that I change the int counter to Board counter.

Comment: Because you  `public static Board[][] board = new Board[numCols][numRows];` define a 2D Array of Boards. You could do as quick fix change the type to int `public static int[][] board = new int[numCols][numRows]` Better solution would be you make a function create board in your Board where you fill up the values and then return the 2D array. But as quick fix just change the type to int it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am just getting one other error doing it the "quick" way. so my error is: The method fillBoard(Class<int[][]>) is undefined for the type Board. I changed my array to: public static int[][] board = new int[numCols][numRows]; as well as System.out.println(Board.fillBoard(int[][]));

Comment: I had changes the following as well                                           
        public static void fillBoard(int[][] a) {
  int counter = 1; 
     for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { //displaying titles down
         for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) { //displaying tiles across
            a[i][j] = counter;
            counter++;
         }
     }
 }

Comment: The undefined error probably because you print the function call and the function does not return anything. Instead print the 2D array either by looping or with Arrays.deepToString

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code is from your class `Play`

```java
public static Board[][] board = new Board[numCols][numRows];
```

This creates an array where every element in the array is null. And this is the array that you pass to method `fillBoard` in class `Board`. Hence in method `fillBoard`, you need to first create a `Board` object and add it as an element to the array. After that you can assign a value to the member variable `number`.

I assume that you want consecutive numbers since each `Board` instance represents a square on the board and in the game of *Snakes and Ladders* the squares are numbered consecutively from 1 (the starting square) to 100. Hence the calculation for determining which value to assign to `number` is...

row index multiplied by length of row plus column index plus one

This is because the *row index* and the *column index* both start from zero (according to the code in your question) and because you want the values to range from 1 to 100 (and not from 0 to 99)

Here is the code that fills your board.

```java
public class Board {
    private boolean snake;
    private boolean ladder;
    private int number;

    Board() {
        snake = false;
        ladder = false;
        number = 0;
    }

    public static void fillBoard(Board[][] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                a[i][j] = new Board();
                a[i][j].number = i * a[i].length + j + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the above code merely answers your question. I'm sure that, as you progress in the development of your game, you will encounter more problems which will prompt you to post more questions. In that case, you **should** post new and separate questions – and not add more questions in comments to this answer.